# Chrome extension: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The error I am getting upon running a chrome extension is the following:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return engine.js:295

Here are lines 293 to 295 so its easier to debug:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.head.childNodes.length; i++)
            if (tryReplace(document.head.childNodes[i])
                            return
```

Am I not properly returning it? Whats the solution?

Comment: Look at your parentheses.

Comment: @SLaks Yup. My bad. Got that fixed. But now a new error pops up same line. That says Illegal return statement. Its the last line I posted. The "return" part

Comment: You're probably trying to return outside of a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses on the second line are out of order:

```
function someFunc() {
  for (var i = 0; i < document.head.childNodes.length; i++)
    // Inserted missing parentheses at the end of the expression.
    if (tryReplace(document.head.childNodes[i]))
      return
}
```

The `return` statement can only be used in the context of a function.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately I now get an error that states Illegal return statement. Problem is line 296 the last line you posted.

Comment: `return` can only be used in the context of a function. I've updated the answer.